# How can I provision salt minion on connect

Tags: salt-stack

I have an AWS setup where I have a designated salt master that accepts all incoming keys and a provisions based on subnet/designated ip addresses. How can I immediately provision my minions on connect without logging into the master server to do so?

Comment: Why the down vote? Isn't this a specific and sensible question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to do this is with the [reactor](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/reactor/) system.  Exactly how to do it depends on what you mean by "on connect".  If you want a minion to highstate every time it connects, then you want to react to the event tag:

```
salt/minion/*/start
```

If you want to execute the highstate *only* when the minion connects for the first time (when its key is accepted), then you'll need to turn off auto-accept, and react to the

```
salt/auth
```

tag.  (In this case, you'll need to accept the key, and then execute the highstate, after waiting for the minion to actually connect.)  Since that's more complicated, I'll show you the first one.  You should be able to extrapolate for the latter case.

First you need to tell the salt-master to react to the tag:

```
# File: /etc/salt/master.d/reactor.conf
reactor:
  - 'salt/minion/*/start':
    - /srv/reactor/highstate.sls
```

And then you need the highstate.sls file:

```
# File: /srv/reactor/highstate.sls
minion_highstate:
  local.state.highstate:
    - tgt: {{ data['id'] }}
```

After implementing this, I get this (with snippage) in my minion log:

```
2016-03-18 23:07:06,009 [salt.cli.daemons ][INFO    ][21627] Setting up the Salt Minion "jhazentest05.example.net"
2016-03-18 23:07:06,219 [salt.cli.daemons ][INFO    ][21627] The salt minion is starting up
2016-03-18 23:07:06,707 [salt.minion      ][INFO    ][21627] Minion is ready to receive requests!
2016-03-18 23:07:06,708 [salt.minion      ][INFO    ][21627] User root Executing command state.highstate with jid 20160318230706334642
2016-03-18 23:07:09,699 [salt.minion      ][INFO    ][21700] Returning information for job: 20160318230706334642
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

John Hazen's approach definitely works. There's also a somewhat simpler option you can enable:  `startup_states`

If you have this set in the minion config, then a highstate will get run each time the minion starts up:

`startup_states: highstate`

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/startup.html

Comment: Do you know if the minion config can be managed from a state? Another useful way of implementing what OP wants would be to have a state that changes the minion config to set `startup_states: highstate` there.

Comment: Yes, you can manage a minion config from a state. Just remember to restart the salt-minion daemon so the changes take effect.